# Can't run Android Test Recorder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso

I use Espresso in my Project with success.
But when I click on record, this append !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yo must add espresso as a dependency like it says on the documentation of the link. 
If you don't add explicitly

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
```

to your build.gradle dependencies it won't work.

Comment: It is define like this in my gradle file. Otherwise I wont run espresso on traditional way.         androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'

Comment: please add your buld.gradle file